# add watermark to multiple video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to transcode the live stream to multiple resolutions  with FFmpeg and also add a watermark to it this is a transcode command which already work fine :

```
argv: [
    '-i',
    'rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test4',
    '-c:v',
    'libx264',
    '-preset',
    'veryfast',
    '-tune',
    'zerolatency',
    '-maxrate',
    '704k',
    '-bufsize',
    '704k',
    '-g',
    120,
    '-r',
    60,
    '-s',
    '640x360',
    '-c:a',
    'aac',
    '-b:a',
    '64k',
    '-f',
    'hls',
    '-hls_time',
    2,
    '-hls_flags',
    'delete_segments',
    '/app/streams/live/test4/b7c30cc4-76c2-4e2d-8a27-aeb6fa61126a/640x360/index.m3u8',
    '-c:v',
    'libx264',
    '-preset',
    'veryfast',
    '-tune',
    'zerolatency',
    '-maxrate',
    '1216k',
    '-bufsize',
    '1216k',
    '-g',
    120,
    '-r',
    60,
    '-s',
    '854x480',
    '-c:a',
    'aac',
    '-b:a',
    '64k',
    '-f',
    'hls',
    '-hls_time',
    2,
    '-hls_flags',
    'delete_segments',
    '/app/streams/live/test4/b7c30cc4-76c2-4e2d-8a27-aeb6fa61126a/854x480/index.m3u8']
```

for the watermark i am not sure how should i do that I tried this :

```
argv: [
    '-i',
    'rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test4',
    '-i',
    '/app/watermarks/b42be7f7-3e94-4f6a-8146-cb965291654f.png',
    '-filter_complex',
    '[0:v][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2',
    '-c:v',
    'libx264',
    '-preset',
    'veryfast',
    '-tune',
    'zerolatency',
    '-maxrate',
    '704k',
    '-bufsize',
    '704k',
    '-g',
    120,
    '-r',
    60,
    '-s',
    '640x360',
    '-c:a',
    'aac',
    '-b:a',
    '64k',
    '-f',
    'hls',
    '-hls_time',
    2,
    '-hls_flags',
    'delete_segments',
    '/app/streams/live/test4/0c66a33a-29d3-41c1-8e48-449f29664fab/640x360/index.m3u8',
    '-filter_complex',
    '[0:v][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2',
    '-c:v',
    'libx264',
    '-preset',
    'veryfast',
    '-tune',
    'zerolatency',
    '-maxrate',
    '1216k',
    '-bufsize',
    '1216k',
    '-g',
    120,
    '-r',
    60,
    '-s',
    '854x480',
    '-c:a',
    'aac',
    '-b:a',
    '64k',
    '-f',
    'hls',
    '-hls_time',
    2,
    '-hls_flags',
    'delete_segments',
    '/app/streams/live/test4/0c66a33a-29d3-41c1-8e48-449f29664fab/854x480/index.m3u8']
```

but this one only add watermark to first movie and not others i must say the length of movie can be increase (for example more than 10 different resolutions) how can add watermark to all of them ?

Comment: Interesting issue.  You could try concat.  `ffmpeg -i concat:"video1.mkv|video2.mkv"` Not sure how that'll go but...nothing ventured, nothing gained!